# Get enclosure tag from RSS feed that has colon in tagname using PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, rss

I am trying to get the image from a RSS feed with an enclosure tag with what I think is a namespace.

```
<enc:enclosure resource="path/to/image" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

I can extract all other fields but it seems with the enc:enclosure I am failing..

I have tried this with no success::

```
'image' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS($node->lookupNamespaceURI('enc:enclosure'), "resource")->item(0)->nodeValue,
'image' =>  $node->getElementsByTagNameNS("enc:enclosure", "resource")->item(0)->nodeValue,
 etc..
```

I get all other tags available using::

```
title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
```

What would be the correct way to extract that enclosure tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling [`lookupNamespaceURI()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.lookupnamespaceuri.php), you should just pass the prefix, you are passing the whole prefix and node name.

```
'image' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS($node->lookupNamespaceURI('enc'), "enclosure")
                       ->item(0)->getAttribute("resource")
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for a while